# document.getElementById and several same IDs in the HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

I have three headings with the same ID. All headings are yellow but I would like to change color. I have used the following code but only the first Hello1 is changed to red. My idea was that all heading with id="MP" should be now red. What did I do wrong?

I have also tried with TagName but the result is worse - all headings are still yellow :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body> 
        <h1 id="MP" style="color: #ffff00; font-size: 20px;">Hello1</h1>
        <h1 id="MP" style="color: #ffff00; font-size: 15px;">Hello2</h1>         
        <h1 id="MP" style="color: #ffff00; font-size: 10px;">Hello3</h1>  
             <script type="text/javascript"> 
                document.getElementById("MP").style.color="red";
                //document.getElementsByTagName("h1").style.color="blue";
             </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: *I have three headings with the same ID.* <-- You're not allowed to do that. It's invalid HTML.

Comment: Ok, now I have three headings with the same class name (class names should not be unique) and try to use document.getElementsByClassName("MP").style.color="red"; But nothing is happening, all headings are still yellow. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're trying to set the color of the collection of elements, which can't be done. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, it is invalid to have multiple elements with the same `id`. [The purpose of an `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) is to uniquely identify an element, so having more than one with the same `id` defeats that purpose.

Next, [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) (notice it's not called `.getElementsById()`) only returns a reference to the first matching element it finds, so after finding the first one, it stops and that's why only the first `h1` is changing its color.

If you want to group together elements that are somehow related, you can give them all the same [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). Then, you can locate all the class members with [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). This will return a collection, [which you can then loop over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and work with each element within the collection as you wish.

Also, avoid inline styles whenever you can. As you saw with your original code, you had to repeat the same styling instructions 3 times because you wanted the same style in 3 places. Instead, create a pre-defined CSS class that each of the elements can just use.

Here all that is put together.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Styling with JavaScript</title>
  
  <style>
    /* Use pre-defined CSS classes whenever possible
       instead of inline styles in your HTML    */
    .heading { color: #ffff00; font-size: 20px; }
    
    .newColor { color:#00f; }
  
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- See how clean the HTML is now? -->
  <h1 class="heading">Hello1</h1>
  <h1 class="heading">Hello2</h1>         
  <h1 class="heading">Hello3</h1> 

  <script> 
    // Get all the elements that match the CSS selector
    // passed into .querySelectorAll() into a collection
    // and loop over the collection
    document.querySelectorAll(".heading").forEach(function(element){
      // Override the original color by adding an additional class
      element.classList.add("newColor");
    });
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turns out, we have a dupe for this problem too... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's not a dupe of this question and actually is centered around the use of live node lists, which should almost always be avoided, especially in loops.

Answer (score 0):

> I have three headings with the same ID.

This is the problem! IDs are meant to be unique! Use a class attribute for this!

[More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

Here is says: *If the id value is not the empty string, it must be unique in a document.*

Comment: If you do not have access to change the structure of your document, you can use `document.querySelectorAll("#MP");` to get access to all elements with this `id`.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("#MP").style.color="red"; did not work for me

Comment: This explains a little of the problem, but not the solution. Since the problem is really explained in the link, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus — "Use a class attribute" — It provides the solution.

Comment: @Quentin Is that really a solution or something that the OP now has to Google?

Comment: @ScottMarcus — Answers shouldn't need to provide introductory guides to basic concepts.

Comment: @Quentin I think that depends on how someone gauges "basic". It's pretty clear the OP doesn't know about classes, so just saying "use classes" isn't super helpful.